# How to automatically create a copy of a list that filters out rows that have/do not have contents in a specific column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to manage a customer list. 
I have a sheet that has all customers on it. 
Some customers have emails, and others don't.

From this full list, I need to create two separate lists.

1. A list of customers that DO have emails.
2. A list of customers that do NOT have emails.

Ideally, I am looking for something that will update as data is entered in the full list.  This is because I am only a part time worker, and those that use this file everyday are, frankly, not at all tech savvy.

So I want to set some formulas up so that the other people at work don't have to do anything at all other than adding rows for a new customer or deleting rows to remove a customer.

[The full list looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3w3L.png)

Is there any way I can get a list on a separate sheet that produces only ahsoka tano and han solo (for the no-emails list)?

And any way to get a list on a separate sheet that produces only darth vader, kylo ren, an padme amidala (for the emails list)?

I have tried playing with Vlookup, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

1. Do a sort. Sort on email. The emails will rise to the top and the customers without emails will be on the lower half of the list. Now you can move the customers from there. Then sort your list again.
2. There is a second method, apply a filter on the email column, "not blank". Both are sufficient to get two lists.

   A formula won't sort emails for you, but if you want it automated, then record a "macro". To set up a macro, you have to make sure that you have "developer" tab opened.

Automation:

> Set up macro, enable:
> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-or-run-in-developer-mode-1b4a8529-3094-432a-9a7f-53935089e5ed
>
> Record a macro?
> http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2.html

What is a macro? It's just like this, "Watch me click and sort and then do it again when I ask you". It's explained in detail in the links above.